# Get Service Principal Owner details?

Tags: azure-active-directory

I’m trying to find some details about who created a certain Service Principal in AAD. In my case, it is a Service Catalog Managed application. When I’m trying to use the `Get-AzureADServicePrincipalOwner` cmdlet and pass the `object ID` of the managed app, I get a null. Is there some way I can see **who has created the app**? More specifically, I'm looking at REST APIs that can give me this information.

Any pointers would be very helpful.

Thank you!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A user who is the `owner` of a service principal does not mean that he is the creator of it. If you want to see who has created the app, you could use the Microsoft Graph API - [`List directoryAudits`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/api/directoryaudit-list?view=graph-rest-1.0&tabs=http) to do that.

Try the query as below in the [Graph Explorer](https://developer.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/graph-explorer#), it works fine on my side.

**Note**: It can only get results for up to `30` days, if the service principal was created before that, you will not be able to get that.

```
GET https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/auditLogs/directoryAudits?$filter=targetResources/any(tr:tr/id eq '<Objetct-id of the service principal>') and activityDisplayName eq 'Add service principal'
```

[image]

Comment: Yeah owners can be assigned separately. In some cases like with groups the creator might become an owner, but they could be removed afterwards.

Comment: @JoyWang, if I sign-in the Graph explorer using my work account, it is expecting me to give certain permissions to Graph explorer which requires admin consent. Is there a way I can use another REST client? What is the audience against which I need to generate my bearer token?

Comment: @AmoghNatu No matter the way to call the api, you need the [permissions](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/api/directoryaudit-list?view=graph-rest-1.0&tabs=http#permissions), you can use the [Microsoft Graph SDK](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/api/directoryaudit-list?view=graph-rest-1.0&tabs=csharp#example), but you also need the permission. The audience should be `https://graph.microsoft.com`.

Comment: I have added `Read all audit log data`  permission on azure portal still getting 401 though I am global admin of my tenant. Do you have any clue for that error?

Comment: @MdFaridUddinKiron If your user account is the global admin, you should be able to do that, could you use it in the Graph Explorer or in the portal -> AAD -> Audit logs?

Comment: Yeah, I used 'Graph Explorer` but got `Authentication_RequestFromUnsupportedUserRole`  message is "User is not in the allowed roles"

Comment: @MdFaridUddinKiron This link may be helpful:https://stackoverflow.com/a/58394509/9455659